# Expo Location returns "null" when trying to Geocode location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, geocoding

I'm trying to Geocode an address, but when I return it to the console, it says "null" Why is this, and what am I doing wrong?

I don't know if the async functions are in the wrong usage.

It might also be the useState

Please help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import Map from './MapView/map';
import * as Location from 'expo-location'

const MainMap = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  convertAddress = (address, label) => {
      (async () => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
          return;
        }
  
        let coords = await Location.geocodeAsync(address)
  
        let data = {
          label: label,
          latitude: coords[0]["latitude"],
          longitude: coords[0]["longitude"]
        }
  
        setData(data)
  
  
      })();    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    convertAddress("4260 La Salle Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90062", "Random Place");
  }, []);

  console.warn(data) // Returns null

  return ( 
    <>
      <Map markers={data} />
    </>
  ) 
} 
export default MainMap;
```

Comment: tested return null then Object {
  "label": "Random Place",
  "latitude": 34.0057024,
  "longitude": -118.3053906,
} for each render , emulator android api33 with google services

Comment: could you please elaborate on this? How can I fix it, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with physical device or other platform ,  share your platform props like  : IOS or android , emulator physical device  , ...version ,